# Is it possible to use a 2.6.38 kernel with 10.10?

Tags: 10.10, kernel, updates

I have simple question. Is it possible to use new 2.6.38 kernel with Ubuntu 10.10? Does there exists some PPA or you need to compile?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can also use the debs coming from Natty... Just go [here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/source/natty/linux) and download the "linux-image-2.6.38-*" and the needed "linux-headers-2.6.38-*" you want and install the debian files. They should work with no issues.

Comment: `linux-headers-*` do not need to be installed for updating the kernel, it's only needed when you need to compile modules for the kernel version, e.g. if you're using VirtualBox. Besides that, +1 for "they should work with no issues". The dependencies for [natty](http://packages.ubuntu.com/natty/linux-image-2.6.38-6-generic) and [maverick](http://packages.ubuntu.com/maverick/linux-image-2.6.35-27-generic) do not differ and newer kernels generally work well with older Ubuntu's. If it doesn't, it won't hurt. You've still your older kernel in case it doesn't work.

Comment: That's quite the list of packages to download - how does this solution differ from @flammon's answer?

Comment: @Oxwivi: Instead of installing all packages matches by **linux-image-2.6.38-\***, install the ones with the `-generic` suffix: `linux-image-2.6.38-generic`.

Answer (score 1):

Here are the files that you need.

http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v2.6.38-natty/

Comment: These are mainline builds, as such they do not contain any Ubuntu patches.  It is safer to use the Natty kernels for this case.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible.

I didn't found any PPA repositories offering 2.6.38 for Maverick. However, I found [this site](http://www.megatek.net.br/customkernels/).

It doesn't look very promising (Portuguese, CSS copied from kernel.org), but I don't think they are trying to mimic kernel.org. For installation, download the `.deb` file and open it with package manager or from terminal with `dpkg -i filename.deb`.

Comment: Do keep in mind though that because there's no backports or PPA repositories, you can't guarantee that the kernel will operate 100% correctly.

Comment: @EvilPhoenix: PPA repository do not ensure any kind of testing or operability.

Comment: considering i was extremely tired when i posted my first comment, i realize now you're right :P  my mistake.

Comment: The site that you refer is not spanish, it's portuguese. Just for the records. Brazilians speaks portuguese no spanish. Regards, Maxi

Answer (score -1):

You could compile it with KernelCheck.

Comment: Can you explain how to do so?

Comment: @ObsessiveFOSS just download the deb file and run there's nothing to it

Comment: Can you add that as an edit?